# Having issues with file naming

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, filenames, naming-conventions

File name 'c:/Users/Mfoniso/Documents/CODE/NODE/meals-backend/src/models/mealModel.js' differs from already included file name 'c:/Users/Mfoniso/Documents/CODE/NODE/meals-backend/src/models/MealModel.js' only in casing.
The file is in the program because:
Root file specified for compilation
Imported via './../models/mealModel' from file 'c:/Users/Mfoniso/Documents/CODE/NODE/meals-backend/src/controllers/MealController.js'ts(1149)

I am trying to import a Model, mealModel.js and this is exactly how the file is named,mealModel.js so I don't know why it now requires a titleCase MealModel when that is not how it is named.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an auto-import extension of vscode, you should consider that it can import all files and components in Capital format. It doesn't matter for development but when you want to deploy this project on Linux os, it can make error for you. **Linux** is case sensitive in usage of files.

Totally, It is suitable to define all your components or modules in a single format. And be careful about import and usage of these when you get help from other extension

Comment: I am not using an auto import extension